# How to prepare a model to return json_encode result ( Codeigniter )

Tags: php, arrays, json, codeigniter

Here is my Model in Codeigniter with foreach loop in it.

Function.

```
  public function get_projectcount($qup) {
    echo'[';
    foreach ($qup as $row) {
        $id = $row['myid'];
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('projects');
        $this->db->where(array('projects.accountId' => $id));
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $projects_count = count($query->result());
        echo '{"myid":"' . $row['myid'] . '",';
        echo '"total_projects":"' . $projects_count . '"},';
    }
    echo']';
}
```

I want this as a result of json_encode.

Comment: You should return it instead of echoing it out so that you can use it later on. And you should not build json manually but always use `json_encode`.

Comment: can you explain how to make this thing as json encode

Comment: Are you getting an array within your controller than just use `return json_encode($qup)`

Comment: The comma after the very last element will cause problems with json_decode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change your function to:

```
public function get_projectcount($qup) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($qup as $row) {
        $id = $row['myid'];
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('projects');
        $this->db->where(array('projects.accountId' => $id));
        $query = $this->db->get();

        $projects_count = count($query->result());
        $result[] = array("myid" => $row['myid'], "total_projects" => $projects_count);
    }
    return json_encode($result);
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the change. My question is updated a bit. for future users :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($qup as $row) {
    $id = $row['myid'];
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $this->db->where(array('projects.accountId' => $id));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $projects_count = count($query->result());
    array_push($data,array(
             'my_id' => $row['myid'],
             'total_projects' => $projects_count
         )
    );
}
json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```