# Return only one row and modify it before sending from model to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to return only one row from my model to controller, before passing it to controller i have to add some more parameters to it such as given below:

```
$condition = "id =" . "'" . $id . "'";
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('subject');
$this->db->where($condition);
$this->db->limit(1);
$query = $this->db->get();

if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
return $query->result(); 
} else {
return false;
}
```

i have want to do something like this while returning it to controller

```
if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
$rows[]=$query->result(); 
$rows['main1']='aaaa';
return $query->result(); 
} else {
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just grab the `row_array` and append a value to it like such:

```
if($query->num_rows() == 1){

    $resultArray = $query->row_array();
    $resultArray['main1']='aaaa';

    return $resultArray;

} else {

    return array();

}
```

Comment: nullReference- It is not working. I can't get main1 key in controller

Answer (score 0):

Use `$query->row()` to fetch single rows from database and you can direction write your condition as  `$this->db->where('id', $id);`

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('subject');
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
       $res= $query->row();
       return $res->column_name;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

In controller

```
function your_function() {
        $this->load->model('your_model');
        $res['name'] = $this->your_model->your_function($id);
       $this->load->view('your_view',$res);
    }
```

Comment: Saty: Can i get the row_array before returning it to a view

Comment: such as append this $res['name']='science'; to result

Comment: but i want to do it in my model

Comment: if i do like this  $res= $query->row();    $res['name']='ggggg'; return $res;  i do not get column appended.Please help to sort out this issue.

Comment: I want to add static keys to the result returned from model to controller, $res= $query->row(); then i have to add one result total_no_of_students to this $res result something like this $res['tot_students']='126'; when i access it in my controller i must get all the result in one. because i am dealing with webservices.

Comment: there is no need of view

Comment: use json_encode in model like `return json_encode(your_array)`

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29230238/how-to-prepare-a-model-to-return-json-encode-result-codeigniter

Comment: but what about adding my own additional key to an array return from database.

Comment: My main problem is this only

Comment: you can add your key as `array("your_key" => your_value);return json_encode(your_array)` what is problem in that

Comment: I want to do it here $res= $query->row();   return $res->column_name; the scenario does not allow me to add it anywhere else. I want something like in $res['no_of_students']='1'; then return $res to model like this return $res.